# Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "java.util.List.get(int)" is null when handling a form

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a form where I have to display a checkbox for each step and an input to choose the position of the step.

So, I would like to add each checked step in the database, with the input also retrieved.
Here is my form:

```
<th:block th:each="etape: ${etapes}">
            <input class="form-label mt-4" type="checkbox" name="etapes" th:field="*{etapes}" th:value="${etape.id}"/>
            <label th:text="${etape.poste.name}"></label>
            <input class="form-label mt-4" type="number" name="positionsPoste" th:field="*{positionsPoste}" th:placeholder="#{new.cheminementEtape.positionPoste.label}"
            />
            <br>
        </th:block>
```

and my service:

```
List<CheminementEtape> cheminementEtapes = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<cheminementForm.getEtapes().size(); i++) {
            for(int y=0; y<cheminementForm.getPositionsPoste().size(); y++){
                CheminementEtape cheminementEtape = CheminementEtape.builder().disable(false).etape(cheminementForm.getEtapes().get(i)).cheminement(cheminement).positionPoste(cheminementForm.getPositionsPoste().get(y)).build();
                cheminementEtapes.add(cheminementEtape);
            }
        }
        this.cheminementEtapeService.add(cheminementEtapes);
        return cheminement;
```

and my form:

```
@Data
public class CheminementForm {
    @NotNull(message = "{cheminement.form.name.notEmpty}")
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String name;

    @NotNull(message = "{cheminementEtape.form.etape.notEmpty}")
    private List<Etape> etapes;


    @NotNull(message = "{cheminementEtape.form.positionPoste.notEmpty}")
    private List<Integer> positionsPoste;
}
```

So I make two for loops, and for each checked step, I get the position input and I add it in the database with the retrieved values.

However, when I do this, I get an error:
Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "java.util.List.get(int)" is null
at line 60

I don't understand... Any ideas ? thanks in advance